# Limits of functions from the left and the right

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

### Question 1

I have a problem with (c) of the following question:

### [image]

When approaching this problem, my thought process is as follows:

- In order to sketch this function, I need to know how it behaves at key points.
- If I find $\lim\limits_{x \to a^-} f(x)$, $\lim\limits_{x \to a^+}f(x)$, and $\lim\limits_{x \to a} f(x)$, I'll have enough information to plot this function out, barring whether I'll need to find where the function crosses the x or y axes.
- If $\lim\limits_{x \to a^-} f(x)$ NOT = $\lim\limits_{x \to a^+}f(x)$, then $\lim\limits_{x \to a} f(x)$ = N/A.

In order to find $\lim\limits_{x \to a^-} f(x)$, I thought I had to set $a$ = -4 and solve, but apparently, according to the answer sheet, the limit is 0. Since I am meant to sketch out this function, it must be true that I can evaluate $\lim\limits_{x \to a^-} f(x)$ and $\lim\limits_{x \to a^+}f(x)$ without using the function plotted as a guide, but I don't know how to do this, since plugging in $-4$ doesn't seem to be right here. Why is my thinking wrong, and how do I go about this problem?

### Question 2

In addition, I have another thing bothering me. This one has to do with (b).  $\lim\limits_{x \to a} f(x)$ here does not exist due to the rule in my third bullet point, but upon graphing out the function, the function appears continuous and is defined at a = -6. How can both be the case?

Comment: Regarding (a) the function reduces to 1 on the right of x=4 and -1at its left, the right and left limits are different then the global limit at 4 does not exist. The case (c) you have the function |x| translated of 4 on the right then its (global) limit at x=4 exists. Regarding the function (b) it's defined for x>-6 so you can evaluate only its right limit and it's equal to -6. Plotting them is pretty easy

Comment: @twinprime For (b), why is it x>-6 and not x>=-6? -6 seems to be a valid input for the function there, does it not? It would be -6. And for these problems, is there a general intuition? How do I know to plug in values for (a), where I get 1 and -1, and use analysis of the function in general for (b)? I seemed to approach the two problems quite differently.

Comment: yes, you're right, I forgot the = in defining the domain of the function (c). The general approach is: find the domain of definition of the function you're studying, then try to figure out what happens at the "special" points of your functions, for example x=4 for (a) and (c). This is elementary calculus as the absolute value |x| is defined as x for x>0 and -x for x<0. In case (a) f(x)=(x-4)/(x-4)=1 for x-4>0, f(x)=-(x-4)/(x-4)=-1 for x-4<0 and isn't defined at x=4. Similar argument holds for case (c). Anyway, more detailed answers are written below.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

For question 1)
$$
\frac{(x-4)^2}{|x-4|}=\frac{(x-4)}{|x-4|}(x-4)=[\mbox{sgn}(x-4)]\cdot(x-4)=|x-4|
$$

For question 2)

we have obviously:
$$
\lim_{x\to -6^+}\sqrt{x+6}+x=-6
$$
but the limit from left does not exists because the function is not defined ( 
for real values).

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, but I have some misunderstandings with this answer. Firstly, what does sgn mean, and how did you consequently simplify question 1 into $|x-4|$? And for question 2) How do I know the limit from the right does not exist? How do I know it's not defined for real values? What do I plug in for $\lim\limits_{x \to -6^+} f(x)$ that is different to $\lim\limits_{x \to -6^-} f(x)$?

Comment: sgn  is the sign function (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function)that gives the sign of $(x-4)$ so the product of this sign with $(x-4)$ is the modulus of $(x-4)$.

Comment: For  question 2): My mistake! I used confused right and left. Now I edit.

Answer (score 0):

for a) we get $$f(x)=\frac{x-4}{x-4}=1$$ for $$x>4$$
and $$f(x)=-\frac{x-4}{x-4}=-1$$ if $$x<4$$ therefore
$$\lim_{x\to 4^+}f(x)=1$$ and $$\lim_{x\to4^-}f(x)=-1$$ and the $$\lim_{x\to 4}f(x)$$ doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

For $x>4$, $|x-4|=x-4$; for $x<4$, $|x-4|=-(x-4)$. Thus the function in (a) can be represented as
$$
f(x)=\begin{cases} -1 & x<4 \\[4px] 1 & x>4 \end{cases}
$$

The function in (c) can be rewritten using the fact that $t^2=|t|^2$:
$$
f(x)=\frac{(x-4)^2}{|x-4|}=\frac{|x-4|^2}{|x-4|}=|x-4|
$$
(for $x\ne4$).

The limits at $4$ can be computed easily, can't they?

The function in (b) isn't defined for $x<-6$, so you can surely consider the limit for $x\to-6^+$. Depending on the conventions used by your textbook, the limit for $x\to-6$ might be deemed non existent. Check with the definition.

How can you sketch the function in (b)? Write $y=\sqrt{x+6}+x$, so $(y-x)^2=x+6$ and
$$
x^2-2xy+y^2-x-6=0
$$
This is a parabola with a sloped axis; the graph of $f$ is part of it.

Comment: To find the limit of |x-4| itself from the left hand and right hand side -- how does one do that without looking at the graph of the function itself? And how could I sketch (a)? Other than plugging in values and extending the lines since the graph is linear.

Comment: @sangstar The function $g(x)=|x-4|$ is continuous.